# What are the connectors used in the arduino mega?

Tags: arduino-mega

I am trying to build a shield for an arduino mega.For that i need to know the type of the female connectors that are soldered in the pins of the arduino mega in order to choose the correct male connectors.

Comment: What kind of shield are you trying to build? Have you looked at the Arduino documentation...? Take a look! [Mega link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega)

Comment: Those are standard 0.1inch female/male headers.

Comment: I looke for sure but couldn't find anything about mechanical design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for male pin header strip, with 0.1 inch (2.54mm) pitch.

In single and dual row form.

Specifically they are:

- 8x1 ADCL
- 8x1 ADCH
- 8x1 PWML
- 8x1 PWMH
- 8x1 Communication
- 6x1 Power
- 18x2   digital IO (on the side)

Source: [Schematics](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-mega-schematic.pdf)